# I want to import csv files to excel file with vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code that importing multiple CSV files to excel. this code works fine but I should edit it little more. I need to copy and paste a fixed range, for example, A1 to C10 of each CSV files and paste it in master excel file. actually, I have multiple CSV files and I need the data that copy from one CSV files to paste in under previous data that has already paste. I'm new to VBA and need help. thx

I tried to declare a fixed range. but it seems to be not right. I couldn't understand what is that line exactly does.

```
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Copy xSht.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)

Sub ImportCSVsWithReference()
    Dim xSht  As Worksheet
    Dim xWb As Workbook
    Dim xStrPath As String
    Dim xFileDialog As FileDialog
    Dim xFile As String
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Set xFileDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    xFileDialog.AllowMultiSelect = False
    xFileDialog.Title = "Select a folder [DataImporter]"
    If xFileDialog.Show = -1 Then
        xStrPath = xFileDialog.SelectedItems(1)
    End If
    If xStrPath = "" Then Exit Sub
        Set xSht = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    If MsgBox("Clear the existing sheet before importing?", vbYesNo, "DataImporter") = vbYes Then xSht.UsedRange.Clear
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    xFile = Dir(xStrPath & "\" & "*.csv")
    Do While xFile <> ""
        Set xWb = Workbooks.Open(xStrPath & "\" & xFile)
        Columns(1).Insert xlShiftToRight
        Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlBlanks).Value = ActiveSheet.Name
        ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Copy xSht.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        xWb.Close False
        xFile = Dir
    Loop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
    MsgBox "no files csv", , "DataImporter"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code are pretty sofisticated, and seens to work well to me.

The code set a FilePicker to select what to import, and after create a new sheet to paste values, copy and paste in main sheet (xSht)

Explanation:

```
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Copy xSht.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
```

"Activesheet.UsedRange.Copy" means you will copy the first row to last column that are filled (in other words, your entire table), and copy into ClipBoard

"xSht.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)", means you go to your main sheet and count all rows filled in D column (probably one column required, to avoid blank registers), and go to the end, offset +1, in other words "New Line".

But doing like this it will paste the new data in D column, but you said want to put in A column.

To do this, change that line to:

```
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Copy xSht.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
```

or if your A is not trustable

```
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Copy xSht.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, -3)
```